# UISlider minimum and maximum track tint clear color iOS 7.1 bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uislider

I seem to be having an issue that I was not having using iOS 7.0 in my app, it now only appears on iOS 7.1. The problem I'm having is that when I set the minimum and maximum `trackTintColor` properties to a clear color, I'm now left with what I call an "artifact" to the left of the `UISlider` that was not present on iOS 7.0. I've tried to iterate through the sublayers and or subviews to set this "artifact" to a clear color, but I cannot seem to hide it. I'm attaching a screenshot below with an arrow pointing to the "artifact".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay so I solved this already by using these two lines of code replacing the trackTintColor properties altogether:

```
[self.colorSlider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.colorSlider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Nice workaround. If this is a change in behavior from iOS 7, though, I hope you'll also report it as a bug. They really screwed up UIProgressView's `progressImage` in iOS 7.1...

Comment: Does no good to report it usually, as we still have to correct the bug for users who currently will be on 7.1 forever.